# Find the process that is setting time

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, time, ntp

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in a VirtualBox VM. I need the system time to not be synchronized with NTP because I have another process that gets time updates from a non-NTP source, setting RTC in localtime. So, I ran `sudo timedatectl set-ntp 0` to disable NTP syncronization. I confirmed that it is off with

```bsh
$ timedatectl status
                      Local time: Fri 2003-05-09 01:45:21 GMT
                  Universal time: Fri 2003-05-09 01:45:21 UTC
                        RTC time: Thu 2019-10-24 15:57:15
                       Time zone: Atlantic/Reykjavik (GMT, +0000)
       System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: no
                 RTC in local TZ: yes

Warning: The system is configured to read the RTC time in the local time zone.
         This mode can not be fully supported. It will create various problems
         with time zone changes and daylight saving time adjustments. The RTC
         time is never updated, it relies on external facilities to maintain it.
         If at all possible, use RTC in UTC by calling
         'timedatectl set-local-rtc 0'.
```

Yet I still see that system time is being set by some process other than my custom time source monitoring process. Is there a way for me to at least figure out which PID is setting the time? What else do I need to do to **really** disable NTP synchronization? Is this a VirtualBox thing only or will I have the same problem when running on real hardware?

Comment: If this is a VM, then VirtualBox is likely serving your own hardware clock as the RTC clock for the VM.  You need to check your VM settings to see if there's a setting to tell VBox to serve your system's time as the RTC clock to the VM.  (This is NOT NTP but a VirtualBox thing).  If you are using real hardware and a bare metal install, disabling NTP should be sufficient to disable time sync (however you are liable then for time drift on your system and correcting for that yourself)

Comment: `VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1
T`  OR  disable time sync: there's a checkbox in the VirtualBox Guest Additional.

Comment: Is there a way to do this directly from the guest, rather than from the host?